# Jest tests fail after adding Typescript to a React Native project

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

So, I just added TypeScript to an existing React Native project (first commit dates from Feb 2016), and I'm getting the follwing errors when running unit tests (using Jest):

1. This is the one that is showing in most files, I'd say 30 out of 38 failed tests
   [image]
2. This one already has a mock in the mock files
   [image]
3. This one shows up on two files
   [image]
4. This one shows up on just one file
   [image]

This only happens when adding ts, I've only modified three files from the project to use it as I have to go slowly because it's a huge project.

I've tried out with different setups for jest.config.js but nothing changes:

jest.config.js

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets');

module.exports = {
    ...tsjPreset,
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            babelConfig: true,
        }
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
    preset: 'react-native',
    transform: {
        ...tsjPreset.transform,
        '^.+\\.(js)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(texts/@debitoor/react-native-sunstone/))/'],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./app",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "paths": {
            "common": ["./common"]
        },
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": false,
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "babel.config.js",
        "metro.config.js",
        "jest.config.js"
    ]
}
```

I tried removing the exclude elements at same thing happens. Not sure what else I'm missing.

I also tried using ts-jest but nothing changed either.

This is the tsconfig.jest.json file:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

I've searched around and in most articles/sites they always talk about starting fresh, but I've already got everything else setup and can't really change much without taking too much time.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Have you fixed this? I have the same problem now.

Comment: @Heaven Nope, didn't manage to keep working on it and I switched projects so I don't think I'll fix it any time soon. If you find an answer or something please let me know to close this one, but in all honesty I think it's easier to just start a project from scratch in a case like this.

Comment: I already fixed it. But we may be dealing with a different problem. My issue is I already config `jest` in the package.json file but I add an extra `jest.config.js` file when I adding Typescript to the React Native project. After I removed the redundant `jest.config.js` file. The problem was solved.